# Adding options to a select and selecting one on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a select, and I am filling the options using javascript. Something like

```
    var select = document.getElementById("selectBox");

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.innerHTML = data[i].name;
        option.value = data[i].id;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
```

It works fine on Firefox and Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer. When I check the html generated on IE I see

```
    <select id="selectBox"/>
```

Is there something I can do for it to work on IE?

**EDIT** 
After refreshing the html page on development tools(IE doesn't do this after the html change) I see that the options have been added, but there seems to be a problem assigning the value, I'm using

```
select.value = theValue;
```

Comment: how do you see the generated HTML on IE ?

Comment: what version of IE are you using ? it works fine in IE9 and IE10. And i see nothing in your code that could prevent it from running in IE8.

Comment: Works fine in IE8, just tested.

Comment: @mohkkhan  I see the html in tools-development tools (or pressing F12)

Comment: Your browser mode might be 10 but documents mode might be quirks...
Put this meta tag in head section...
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was where I was getting the selected value from. I was using ajax calls, and IE was (I think) caching the response. When I changed some value, the server had to give me the correct select option, but it was giving me wrong one since IE was always reading the same answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use `add` instead of `appendChild`:

```
select.add(option);
```

Also, using the `Option` constructor can save you some lines of code:

```
var option = new Option(data[i].name, data[i].id);
```

Comment: My solution is [perfectly valid](http://jsfiddle.net/Ucx2a/1/). Can I have some explanation for the downvote?

Comment: Yes, but its ugly. Sorry. Just a matter of subjective taste. Nothing personal.

Comment: @c69 "Ugly"? Are you kidding me? That's basic Javascript API. You should vote down a *bad answer*.

Comment: omg, its even [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535921.aspx) :( upvoting your answer now. Opinion stands, though.

Comment: but edit your answer, 'coz i cant change my vote now - 10 minutes have passed.

Comment: @c69 Done. Really, those `<select>` specific methods are often oversighted. Sometimes, even by the W3C itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

Javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById("selectBox"),
    data = [{ name: "y", id: "b" }, { name: "z", id: "c" }],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    
    option.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[i].name));
    // or alternately
    //option.text = data[i].name;
    option.value = data[i].id;
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ZABGw/)

And of course there is the standards compliant method [`HTMLOptionElement.Option()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement.Option) as described by @MaxArt

Comment: It's about `<select>` elements, not `<option>`.

Comment: @MaxArt, I'm pretty sure that it is the same issue, but haven't been able to find an actual bug report for it. So, I will remove that information.

Comment: Actually it seems there *is* some sort of odd behaviour setting `innerHTML` for options in IE<9. Looks like it correctly sets the property, but the `text` property remains empty until the node is appended in the DOM. I've tested it using IE10 in IE8 mode, so take this with a grain of salt. But that's why I think the `new Option/select.add` way works best.

Comment: Basically both `innerHTML` and `Internet Explorer` are best avoided whenever possible. :)

Comment: Well `innerHTML` - a property introduced by Microsoft - is a godsend for web development, and now it's universally well supported, even in mobile browsers. In the past, it was a shame that IE itself couldn't get it right in some cases (tables were another tricky problem using `innerHTML`).

Comment: Yes, support is much better with other vendors rather than those that introduced it. :) I haven't tried IE10 (I don't use any MS products), but my hope is that they have fixed the majority of such issues and incompatibilities. And yes, I do hope that they continue to innovate (while standardising too).