# Convert PHP For loop to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

Is it possible to change the code below to JavaScript?

```
foreach ($liftdeets as $lifts) {
    echo '<option>'.$lifts["LiftMakes"].'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if we need to "convert" it literally then:

```
<script>
var liftdeets = <?php echo json_encode($liftdeets); ?>;

for (var i = 0; i < liftdeets.length; i++) {
    document.write('<option>' + liftdeets[i]["LiftMakes"] + '</option>');
}
</script>
```

Seems like it does the same as the PHP code mentioned in the question.

P.S. Please note that I'm a bit joking and you should pay attention on answers where we work with DOM tree in a more "elegant" way.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript have a similar method to `foreach` of PHP, here is an example:

```
var test = [
    {a: 1, b: 2,},
    {a: 3, b: 4,}
];

test.forEach(function(val){
    console.log(val.a);
});
```

Comment: `var var`? really? => `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a javascript function for this:

```
function addOptions() {
    var selectDropdownElement = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

    for (var i = 0; i<=100; i++){
        var options = document.createElement('option');
        options.value = i;
        options.innerHTML = i;
        selectDropdownElement.appendChild(options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many way, some are listed here: [Adding options to a select and selecting one on internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559742/adding-options-to-a-select-and-selecting-one-on-internet-explorer)

```
var option = new Option(data[i].name, data[i].id);
```

Since old IE don't like to manipulate `select/option` you should do something like:

```
var HTMLselect = '<select>';
for (var i = 0; i<=100; i++){
    HTMLselect += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
}
HTMLselect += '</select>';
```

That's shorter, faster to execute, and prevent cross platform problems.